# Cycle index of cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show that the cycle index for the cyclic group $C_n$ (the group of rotations of regular $n$-gon) is

$$P_{C_n} (t_1 , \ldots ,t_n)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d\mid n} \phi (d) t_d^{\frac{n}{d}},$$ where $\phi$ is the Euler function.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps**

- First you can write $C_n=\left \{Id,r,\cdots,r^{n-1}\right \}$ with $r$ is the elementary rotation of the $n$-gon.
- Given $0\leq k\leq n$ let $d=\gcd(k,n)$ you can easily see that $\bigl\langle r^k\bigr\rangle=\bigl\langle r^d\bigr\rangle$, and actually $r^d$ and $r^k$ has the same type: they consist of $d$ cycles of length $\frac{n}{d}$
- For every $d$ a divisor of $n$ the number of permutations with the same type as $r^d$ is exactly $\varphi(\frac{n}{d})$ which comes from the number of integers $k$ such that $\gcd(n,k)=d$ and $0\leq k\leq n$
- Conclude

Comment: What is the meaning of this $<r^k>=<r^d>$ statement in the second point.

Comment: $\bigl\langle x\bigr\rangle$ denotes the group generated by $x$.

Comment: Hey can you elaborate the third point a bit? I didn't get how there are exactly $\phi(\frac{n}{d})$ many permutations with same type as $r^d$.

Comment: First, it's equal to the number of integers $0\leq k\leq n$ such that $d=\gcd(k,n)$, this is the same as the number of $0\leq k'\leq \frac n d $ such that $1=\gcd(k',\frac n d)$ and this the definition of Euler's totient function.